# Send message from renderer process to node process with Nightmare

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, nightmare

How can i send message from renderer process (web page) to main process (node) in Nightmare? There's [ipc](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.27.0/api/ipc-main-process/) in Electron and Nightmare is built on the top of Electron so I suppose that it's possible, but I can't figure out how.

Something like that:

http://example.com

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.postMessage('aaaaaaaa', '*');
</script>
```

index.js

```
let nightmare = new Nightmare();
nightmare.on('message', function(e) {
 console.log(e.data); // will output aaaaaaaa
});

nightmare.goto('http://example.com').then(function() {
 console.log('loaded');
});
```

Comment: Could you provide more background on what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Ross I want to load page which can post message to node process from javascript and I don't know how this js should look like.

Comment: I should have been more specific: could you provide sample code that demonstrates what you are trying to do?

Comment: I've updated my question, hope that it's clear now.

Comment: Thank you for the update.  I'll attempt an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to get data from the page, why not use `.evaluate()`?  Something like:

```
nightmare.goto('http://example.com')
    .evaluate(function(){
        var element = document.querySelector('some-element.query');
        return element.value;
    })
    .then(function(value){
        console.log(value);
    });
```

---

To your original example, you cannot send arbitrary events until plugins are allowed on Nightmare down to the Electron instance it wraps.  There was a discussion of adding arbitrary events to Nightmare's core in Nightmare [#354](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/354), which  I tried to fix in Nightmare [#367](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/pull/367).  It was  determined that adding arbitrary events should be a plugin under [#425](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/pull/425).  The plugin PR has not been accepted, but the plugin for the plugin fork [is already completed](https://github.com/rosshinkley/nightmare-custom-event).